# TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined React Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, axios

I have a project uses Express and react, Everything was working fine,

I didn't make any changes to the code suddenly it starts to give this error.

In the previous days, I have upgraded node from 10.15.0 to 12.x and added Axios.

I tested after those changes and it works. now it does not, what this mean??

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Desktop/ahmad/client/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 | 
  44 | /**
  45 |  * Module exports.
*/

View compiled
./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28181:30
__webpack_require__
C:/.../ahmad/client/webpack/bootstrap 4501180ca3adc0d915c0:678
  675 | };
  676 | 
  677 | // Execute the module function
> 678 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
  679 | 
  680 | // Flag the module as loaded
  681 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/.../ahmad/client/webpack/bootstrap 4501180ca3adc0d915c0:88
  85 |      console.warn("[HMR] unexpected require(" + request + ") from disposed module " + moduleId);
  86 |      hotCurrentParents = [];
  87 |  }
> 88 |  return __webpack_require__(request);
  89 | };
  90 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  91 |  return {
View compiled
./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
C:/.../Desktop/ahmad/client/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:22
  19 | var Route = require('./router/route');
  20 | var Router = require('./router');
  21 | var req = require('./request');
> 22 | var res = require('./response');
  23 | 
  24 | /**
  25 |  * Expose `createApplication()`.
*/
View compiled
__webpack_require__
C:/.../Desktop/ahmad/client/webpack/bootstrap 4501180ca3adc0d915c0:678
  675 | };
  676 | 
  677 | // Execute the module function
> 678 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
  679 | 
  680 | // Flag the module as loaded
  681 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/.../Desktop/ahmad/client/webpack/bootstrap 4501180ca3adc0d915c0:88
  85 |      console.warn("[HMR] unexpected require(" + request + ") from disposed module " + moduleId);
  86 |      hotCurrentParents = [];
  87 |  }
> 88 |  return __webpack_require__(request);
  89 | };
  90 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  91 |  return {
View compiled
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found the I have mistakenly typed

`import response from { 'express' }`

I found that this problem happens when you try to call backEnd stuff in your frontEnd.
when I delete that line problem solved.

Edit: it turns out that I didn't type the import statement because I used the word `response` as a variable name, it was automatically imported.
I'm not sure if the import was from React itself or another VS code auto-completion extension.

Comment: My mind was blown where this error came from, I did the same thing lol. Auto import can be dangerous

Comment: thanks this happened to me too. it was an auto import when I typed "response" in a fetch call

Comment: Thanks, man, I got this error and was trying to solve from the past two days.

Answer (score 3):

import response from { 'express' };
got imported
in your actions page by default by "vs code"

Answer (score 3):

While im working with one file, this error suddenly appears. I was then checked the top line and this `import e from 'express'` line appears without knowing why. I just removed it, and it works.

Comment: EXACTLY. I'm sure I was typing `e.target.value` and the robots thought they'd be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { json } from "express"
```

this might be auto imported by vs code or by react so just delete this.

Answer (score 1):

Great! the same problem, I don't use Express. It's happened to me when a create a const request and use the intelligence to complete the sentency. I removed the line

```
 import { request } from 'express';
```

which is automatically added, and the project is already running

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just replace the 'res' in express/lib/response.js
(Replace 'res' with any other variable , 'responsee' worked for me)
(Make sure you replace the 'res' in export statement too)

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me because in a React component when using `handleSubmit`, I forgot to add `e` (event) in the argument and called `e.preventDefault()` inside the function and this e auto imported what has been mentioned above

[Here is the fix screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Hfd.png)

Comment: can you include the code as part of the answer (and not as an image)?

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally installed express and react at the same folder and hence it was not working. I made sperate folders for client/server and then the problem got resolved

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score 0):

After `git clone` my project on another computer I got `import express from "express"` which appeared in the App.js file of the front of my React + Express app