# "Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" everytime I run my application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error every time I try running my application:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
(anonymous function)
F:/first5/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 | 
  44 | /**
  45 |  * Module exports.
```

According to many other posts they say that you have to remove a line from 'actions'? But like **where** and **what** is 'actions'? The other posts haven't been of any help so that is why I am now asking my own question.

Comment: Please see whether this link helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903475/typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined-react-express

Comment: I don't like that post because they say to just remove the line "import response from { 'express' }" but like, where do I remove it from? The post doesn't say. I literally don't know how anyone understood that. How do I know I have it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're importing `response` from `express` on your frontend side.

This can happen when you use a variable named `response`, your IDE can auto-import it from `express`.

Try to find out where you're importing it by searching `import response from`, and then remove it. It could solve the problem.

**Refactored Code**

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const login = function () {
    fetch("", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        key: "test"
      })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        alert(res.message);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={login}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Comment: I only have app.js and nothing else and `import response from` is not present in it.

Comment: if then, can you upload your code to codesandbox?

Comment: Okay, and should I share it then? I'll do it in a bit.

Comment: Okay I tried using codesandbox but it wouldn't actually let me upload my own files.

Comment: Okay nevermind, my smol brain managed to get it over time: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-albattani-6obbk?file=/index.js  -- I hope that works. I still get the same error, it might be due to the other dependencies, not sure.

Comment: @TedBed is this `react-native` project or `react` project?

Comment: I am using expo so I believe it is react-native.

Comment: I am seeing many errors here and there. plz give me some time to refactor everything

Comment: How would I be able to use express then if I'm importing it or anything?

Comment: you should use express on server side not on the frontend side.

Comment: How is there really a clear difference between what's frontend and whats backend? Do I just create a seperate file that uses express then?

Comment: you need to create separate project (or at least separate file)

Comment: I'll have to stick with just making a seperate file because I want to make a mobile app and eventually have it on the app store and I believe it's easier that way. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, thanks for your help!

Comment: In that case, you should separate both projects - React Native and Node.

Comment: You should deploy mobile apps to app stores. And also need to host Node project on any kinda hosting.

Comment: So I could have the backend running on a server I own, and the front-end to reference that?

Comment: Yes. separated backend and frontend