# React and Express: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, npm

Good afternoon,

I am trying to integrate this project https://github.com/pimterry/pi-cam into a React app on my Raspberry Pi Zero W. This project uses express and express-ws.

But it fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
(anonymous function)
node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42
39 | * @public
40 | */
41 |
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
```

(Full log joined).

Along with a compilation warning:

```
./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

I have node v10 and npm v6, steps to reproduce:

- Create new app with npm: `npm init react-app my-app`
- Move to it: `cd my-app`
- Install express modules: `npm i express express-ws`
- Add express reference in index.js: `const express = require('express')`
- Start the application: `npm start`
- The error pops up when connecting to IP_ADDRESS:3000

What I tried:

- If I clone the linked project, then `npm install` and `node index.js`, everything works just fine.
- I tried copying the package.json references to express and express-ws and then `npm install` to have the exact same versions in my React app, but still the error shows.
- This post [TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined React Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903475/typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined-react-express) suggests that updating to node v12 should fix it, as Raspberry Pi Zero W (ARMv6), is no supported by node >= 12, I need to compile it on the Raspberry which takes ages.

EDIT: Managed to install with  `NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release nvm install 12.20.1`
-> Does not solve

- Tried editing webpack.config.js but without success.

EDIT: Tried editing
node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
by adding

```js
      }),
    ].filter(Boolean),
    // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
    // Tell webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
    // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
    // Here I added
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    // End of modification
    node: {
      module: 'empty',
      dgram: 'empty',
      dns: 'mock',
```

The warning disappears, but then nothing show up, as if there was nothing left on the client side, I tried to allow `react` and `react-dom` with webpacks but still nothing.

On the other way I removed the extra statements, but added

```
    node: {
      module: 'empty',
      dgram: 'empty',
      dns: 'mock',
      fs: 'empty',
      http2: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      child_process: 'empty',
      fs: 'empty',
      express: 'empty' // Here
    },
```

But the error still shows.

Can somebody please direct me?

Thanks in advance