# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: reactjs, express, npm, windows-10

Unlike [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903475/typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined-react-express) one, the import is intentional. I need to use the express module. How can I fix that? I've tried but I couldn't make a sample to reproduce it. So I'm open to guesses on what can be the reason for the error. The error is caused by the import:

```
import express from 'express'
```

I also tried:

```
import {express} from 'express'
```

neither does work.

the error:

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/artur/Desktop/merge/editor/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:41
  38 |  * @public
  39 |  */
  40 | 
> 41 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  42 | 
  43 | /**
  44 |  * Module exports.
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Try using require, as noted in docs:

const express = require("express");
const app = express(); // create express app

Also, make sure that you have installed express package (you can check if it's in package.json before running npm install)

Comment: @Nihad I've tried using require, I got the same error. It's in the package.json: `"express": "^5.0.0-alpha.8"`,I've even tried using the most recent version yet I get same error.

Comment: Try to import all objects from the express module and console log them. I.e.:
import * as example from 'express';console.log(example);

According to the error, it seems that you're missing response or some other object of the express module. Please share the entire code or at least comment all except the import statement

Comment: @Nihad the error on the page is the same but the messages on the console window look like this: https://pastebin.com/akT2hVDZ

Comment: Looks like some issues with the webpack config. You can refer to this issue https://fantashit.com/cannot-read-property-defineproperty-of-undefined-webpack/.

Also, if this doesn't help, I would suggest you delete a node-modules directory, comment on all other modules except the express, and rerun the npm install. If the error persists then it's definitely the webpack issue. If not, some of the modules are bugging you, and you need to pinpoint it by repeating the process (delete node-modules dir, uncomment one module, and npm install). Hope this will help

Comment: @Nihad You are my hero.  My failed code: `import {mysql} from "mysql2";`   And here was the fix: `import * as mysql from "mysql2";` with a console log test.  Note its not clear if  `import mysql from "mysql2";` would also have worked.  Still testing.  Many thx.