# Angular - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've an Angular app, and it compiles (`ng serve`) fine, however in the browser I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at 18606 (response.js:43:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 72540 (express.js:22:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 44202 (index.js:11:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 66986 (user-profile.service.ts:103:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 48884 (fire-document.ts:128:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
```

Within the response.js, seems like http.ServerResponse is indeed undefined.

```
var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
```

In my tsconfig.json file, I've stream-http as a path (for polyfill purposes):

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
...
      "http": [
        "./node_modules/stream-http"
      ],
...
```

This path is added because Webpack no longer would add polyfills by default: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20819

Based on my investigation, it may be picking `response` object from `express`: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined React Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903475/typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined-react-express)

I've tried to recreate my app and trying everything, but still have the same issue.

Comment: where and how are you importing ```stream-http``` i tried doing it in new angular project, i am getting error "global is not defined" from capability.js file.